# Out of PAT range

Tags: nfl

Now that the point after touchdown attempt in the NFL makes for a challenging kick, has successive offensive penalties ever taken a team out of range for the PAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Out of range" is subjective, so I will leave it up to the reader to decide.

During the first week of the 2015 season, the Browns converted a 48-yard PAT. [According to ESPN](http://www.espn.com/blog/cleveland-browns/post/_/id/15572/travis-coons-48-yard-extra-point-may-be-an-nfl-record-or-not), this was the longest PAT since 2001, in which the Cardinals converted a 37-yard PAT.

[According to ForTheWin](https://ftw.usatoday.com/2015/09/cleveland-browns-48-yard-extra-point-longest-ever-new-rule-nfl), the Redskins converted a 40-yard PAT in 1987 and is believed to be the longest PAT conversion prior to [the rule changes implemented in 2015](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap3000000493347/article/nfl-moves-extra-point-to-15yard-line-for-2015-season).